# Warning in Jetty 9 Http requests - Under Utilization of N/W in local loopback

Tags: tcp, jetty

I am trying to run Jetty 9 on Ubuntu 12.10 (32 bit). The JVM i am using in JDK 1.7.0_40. I have setup a rest service on my server that uses RestLib. The rest service is a POST method that just receives the data and does no processing with it and responds a success.

I want to see what is the maximum load the Jetty9 server will take with the given resources. I have a Intel i5 processor box with 8 GB memory. I have setup a Jmeter to test this rest in the localhost setting. I know this is not advisable but i would like to know this number (just out of curiosity).

When I run the JMeter to test this POST method with 1 MB of payload data in the body, i am getting a through put of around 20 (for 100 users).

I measured the the bandwidth using iperf to begin with

```
iperf -c 127.0.0.1 -p 8080 
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 127.0.0.1, TCP port 8080

TCP window size:  167 KByte (default)

[  3] local 127.0.0.1 port 44130 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 8080

[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth

[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   196 MBytes   165 Mbits/sec
```

the number 165 MB seems ridiculously small for me but that's one observation.

I ran the server with StatisticsHandler enabled and was observing the request mean time. Also was observing the system resources using nmon monitoring tool.

The CPU usage was around 20 % (overall), 4GB of free memory and the number of threads in the server (monitored using jconsole) around 200 (i had specified max thread count as 2000 in start.ini file).

Jmeter was configured to bombard repeatedly.

I observed the network usage in local loopback interface in nmon tool and it was around 
30 MB. This was inline with the iperf data quoted earlier.

I tried the same experiment with weblogic(using JDK 1.6) and it was using nearly 250 MBps in lo interface. I had explicitly disabled tcp sync cookies in the sysctl config to avoid the limitation due to system thinking the test as DOS attack.

Please help me comprehend this numbers. Am I missing something here in the config. The n/w seems to be a limiting factor here but since it is a loopback interface there is no physical limitation as proved by the Weblogic case.

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong in the Jetty 9 case.

Also I am getting this warning in Jetty9 logs very frequently

> WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp14540840-309: Parsing Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp@1dee6d3{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-}

Comment: i solved this problem. The issue was with me running the server as a foreground process. This was slowing down the through put may be due to printing of the logs in stdout. So i started the server as an init.d process and the problem was solved. Now the throughput is very good.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you tell me how I can start the server as an init.d? Is it by script? If yes, then It's already running by himself. My question is in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510218/jetty-too-much-data-after-closed-for-httpchanneloverhttp/22512066#22512066)

Answer (score 0):

This question is effectively being answered on this mailing list thread:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03906.html

Comment: Please read this mail thread (started by me) to get a good perspective of http load testing methodologies.