# Jetty too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp

Tags: jetty

I'm having trouble with upload one audio file >10s and gives me this error:

```
WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp1359061041-19: badMessage: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp@7fd0cbe{r=5,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

If I upload audio file <10s it goes ok.

I searched on google, but I couldn't find any solution for this.
There's any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Cordova 3.3.0, and the problem was on the upload. The code below solved my case:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=name;
    options.mimeType = "audio/amr";
    options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    }
    options.chunkedMode = false;
```

From why jetty keep giving me the `too much data after closed`(Will try my best to explain). The connection must be closed after do another connection and request. For example, my upload keep reusing the same request and overflow the request and give me the message. So basically, for each request, must close and open new one.

For precaution, I made changes on `jetty.xml`

```
<Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="65536" /></Set>
<Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.request.header.size" default="16384" /></Set>
<Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.response.header.size" default="16384" /></Set>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a similar issue that's discussed here http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03919.html

How are you starting Jetty? Is it from the command line where log information goes to STOUT? If so, you might need to start the app as a service or configure the log level lower.

Comment: I'm starting the server `java -jar start.jar `

Comment: Try running it as a process or redirect the standard out to /dev/null (assuming linux).

Answer (score 0):

To run the server from init.d, copy the script ${JETTY_HOME}/bin/jetty.sh to /etc/init.d/ folder (If you want to start jetty during system boot). Make sure the script has execute permissions. Run the script like

`sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start`   (I have copied jetty.sh as jetty in /etc/init.d/ folder)

Comment: Well it didn't worked for me, I'm passing the file with 15seconds less than 1mb and still giving me the same error.

Comment: I am running a rest service that accepts data on Jetty using the above mentioned command. I am able to upload 100MB easy. Where is the file uploaded to? It might be error of the application running of Jetty (I assume its your app)

Comment: in my local folder: `/home/ubuntu/fileuploaded`, but it's really random when show this error, with 15seconds of audio, sometimes it works and sometimes don't.

Comment: Actually, what I said is wrong. Its not calling any methods on my rest service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the client was sending more **form keys** than the amount that the server was allowed to receive.

So I had to set

```
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.getServletContext().getContextHandler().setMaxFormKeys(1000000000);
```

in the jetty server side.

Answer (score 0):

For Googlers, I ran into this issue and fixed it by changing parameter annotations from `@FormParam` to `@FormDataParam`:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response post(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("file") InputStream file) {
    //...
}
```

to:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response post(
        @FormDataParam("name") String name,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file) {
    //...
}
```

I'm running on Heroku and, having found the solution by chance, have found the following documentation:

- https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.0.3/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataParam.html

Which says:

> This annotation in conjunction with the media type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting and consuming forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I wasn't reading from the input. The error wasn't triggered every time, but when the input became beyond a certain size, these errors would occur. Simple fully reading the input stream before writing to the output stream solved the issue for me.